# Email Address in Web API GET request

Tags: http, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a REST APIs implemented in ASP.NET Web API. One scenario we'd like to support is to do a `GET` request of some user information by email address.

Ideally, clients should be able to do something like this:

```
GET: /api/v1/users/email/your_email@your_domain.com
```

When I attempt to run this GET request, such as through the browser, then I get the [404 Not Found](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942041) page.

What am I doing wrong that is causing IIS to not run the Web API route handler for my route? If I try requesting `/api/v1/users/email/your_email`, then it routes correctly.

Comment: Is it because of "@"? did u try html encoding?

Comment: Yes, I tried url encoding the email before including it in the url.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following and see if it works for you?

```
GET: /api/v1/users/email?id=your_email%40your_domain.com
```

This assumes your controller's Get function is something like this: `Get(string id)`, i.e. it takes a parameter called `id` of type string. If you want it to take, for example, a parameter called "emailAddress", then you would do:

```
GET: /api/v1/users/email?emailAddress=your_email%40your_domain.com
```

Note the `@` sign is encoded as `%40`. This also assumes your controller is called `EmailController`.

Comment: I've just done a quick Web API test. I'm using the default VS2013 ASP.NET Web Application Web API template with the ValuesController class. I changed the controller's second Get function like this: `public string Get(string id)` and in Fiddler I'm composing a GET http request like this: `GET http://.../api/values?id=your_email@your_domain.com` (note I've used the `@` sign unencoded in Fiddler). This returned the expected `value` string in the response. If I composed: `http://.../api/values/your_email@your_domain.com`, then I'd get the 404 you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to test it for you.

The main issue is that "IIS Web Core" confused "." from email address with "." from file extension (e.g.  .aspx  .php and etc)

If you remove "." from email address and replace it with "-" or something then it will work.

Eg.

> GET /api/values/me@gmail-com

```
 public string Get(string id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

Hope it helps.

You may see how to remove the default IIS module but I would recommend to reconsider your API design again.