# Is it possible to include a . (period) in an ActionName?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I would like to know if it is possible to include a period (.) in the ActionName attribute of an ASP.NET WebApi method.

```
[ActionName("RedirectToResource2")]
```

My routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you *try* it? Assuming you did, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No. It will make the engine confused with file extension.

It's similar to this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012184/217593

Hope it helps.

Note: You may see how to remove the default IIS module to accept dot "."..