# How to use email address as optional parameter in HttpAttribute Route

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am using VB on a .net web api 2 site that has HttpAttribute enabled and I am trying to use an email address as an optional parameter in the route definition.

This is the route definition in the controller:

```
    <Route("someController/SomeAction/{id}/{emailAddress?}")>
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function SomeAction(ByVal id As String, Optional ByVal emailAddress As String = "") As HttpResponseMessage
        ' ..do stuff
    End Function
```

If I ommit the optional emailaddress from the request path then the server executes this method.  If I add the emailAddress to the end of the path then I get a 404 Not Found response, eg:

```
 http://myapiserver/some/action/1A2B/ ' <-- route found and the SomeAction method is executed
 http://myapiserver/some/action/1A2B/myemail@mydomain.ex ' <-- not found
```

I tried URL encoding the email value used but still get 404-not found:

```
http://myapiserver/some/action/1A2B/myemail%40mydomain.ex ' <-- also 404-not found
```

I can't be the first person to attempt to send an email address to an API server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you put a non-email-like value as the second parameter? E.g. `http://myapiserver/some/action/1A2B/notAnEmail` ? Does it still execute `SomeAction`?

Comment: Just saw this comment in the "Related" questions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012184/3485669 Could give it a try.

Comment: @Forty3 Putting a simple value in that spot works.  Looking at the other post you referenced made me realize that the server was looking for a file because of the .abc ending on the email address.  Simply adding an ending / to the URL fixes it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be pretty simple.

Just add a / to the end of the URL so that the server knows the email is part of the path:

```
http://myapiserver/some/action/1A2B/myemail@mydomain.ex/ '<-- WORKS!
```

Without the ending slash the server thinks that we are looking for a file because of the .abc ending of the email address.